# Kivy, passing argument using roulette and carousel

Tags: kivy

main:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')
'''
Check aida.kv for the ui design
'''


from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import (ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty)

class Controls(BoxLayout):   
    timer_value = NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controls, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.roulette_time.bind(rolling_value=self.time_changed)  

    def time_changed(self, instance, value):
        self.timer_value = value

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):


    pass

class AidaApp(App):
    pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AidaApp().run()



kv:

# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#:kivy 1.8.0

#:import CyclicRoulette kivy.garden.roulette.CyclicRoulette

WeatherRoot:


<WeatherRoot@BoxLayout>:

    carousel: carousel

    controls: controls


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Carousel:
            id: carousel
            Controls:
                id: controls

<Controls>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.686, 0.635, 0.541, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    roulette_time: rlt_time

    BoxLayout:
        CyclicRoulette:
            cycle: 60
            density: 15
            zero_indexed: True
            selected_value: 5
            width: 50
            background_color: [0.686, 0.635, 0.541, 1]
            id: rlt_time
        Label:
            size_hint: (1, .8)
            text: format(root.timer_value)
            font_size: 50
```

I get an error 'Controls'object has no attribute 'roulette_time
When I set an attribute I get sort of different errors about binding, etc
only works when in kv Controls set to root, but I must have a different class as a root
Please help me to solve this problem, I am stucked

Comment: Please check the code format so it's easier to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `Controls'object has no attribute 'roulette_time'` because nowhere in your Controls class, or anywhere for that matter, do you define a roulette_time variable. Try setting roulette_time = NumericProperty(0) in the Controls class.

```
class Controls(BoxLayout):
    roulette_time = NumericProperty(0)
```

Comment: The kv language line `roulette_time: rlt_time` actually will automatically create the roulette_time NumericProperty in recent versions of kivy, so you don't also need to declare it in the class. But perhaps the OP has an older kivy version, or there's some bug with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that's not working, because it should. An `ObjectProperty` should automatically be created to hold the reference to the `CyclicRoulette` instance.

But - there's an easier way to do this! You're just updating a property on your `Controls` class with that value anyway, so you can directly bind them. Replace this line:

```
roulette_time: rlt_time
```

with:

```
timer_value: rlt_time.rolling_value
```

and whenever the `CyclicRoulette`s `rolling_value` property changes, your `timer_value` on `Controls` will automatically be updated. You don't need to create the `time_changed` method or bind it to the `CyclicRoulette`.

Comment: Would you know how can I pass timer_value variable back to my Controls class, I need to use it for some logic functions?

Comment: `timer_value` is a property on your `Controls` class. You should be able to access the value with `self.timer_value`.

Comment: I can't, it brings value 0

Comment: class Controls(BoxLayout):   
    timer_value=NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controls, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print "Test",self.timer_value

Comment: Don't try to read the property in your init. React to changes in the property by binding to it, or read it after you know the user has chosen the value. During your init the UI isn't even drawn yet.